# How to display days+hours+mins+secs in javascript countdown code?

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

I'm trying to make a countdown clock in javascript to count down to a date. The problem is that I'm trying to make it only show days and hours. Here is my code:

```
var deadline = '2017-06-01';
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
   var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
   var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
   var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
   var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
   var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
   return {
       'total': t,
       'days': days,
       'hours': hours,
       'minutes': minutes,
       'seconds': seconds
   };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var timeinterval = setInterval(function () {
      var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
      clock.innerHTML = 'days: ' + t.days + '<br>' +
                        'hours: ' + t.hours + '<br>' +
                        'minutes: ' + t.minutes + '<br>' +
                        'seconds: ' + t.seconds;
      if (t.total <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timeinterval);
      };
  }, 1000);
}
```

I tried commenting out the seconds and minutes to no success. Exactly what do I need to comment out? Thank you!

Comment: `clock.innerHTML = 'days: ' + t.days + '<br>' + 'hours: ' + t.hours + '<br>';`

Comment: thank you, you are a legend

Comment: Why don't you use the `Date()` function to get the dates? `var t = (new Date(2017,5,1,0,0,0,0) - new Date())/1000;` → t stores the difference between the current moment and 12am on 1st June 2017 in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        var timeinterval = setInterval(function () {
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
            clock.innerHTML = 'days: ' + t.days + '<br>' +
                  'hours: ' + t.hours + '<br>';
            //                      +'minutes: ' + t.minutes + '<br>' +
            //                      'seconds: ' + t.seconds;
            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            };
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Commenting like

```
  clock.innerHTML = 'days: ' + t.days + '<br>' +
                    'hours: ' + t.hours + '<br>' +
                    //'minutes: ' + t.minutes + '<br>' +
                    //'seconds: ' + t.seconds;
```

will result in error because you got a loose `+` at the end. Use

```
  clock.innerHTML = 'days: ' + t.days + '<br>' +
                    'hours: ' + t.hours + '<br>' + ''
                    //'minutes: ' + t.minutes + '<br>' +
                    //'seconds: ' + t.seconds;
```

to secure it.

Answer (score 0):

```
clock.innerHTML = 'days: ' + t.days + '<br>' +
                        'hours: ' + t.hours + '<br>'// + 
                        //'minutes: ' + t.minutes + '<br>' +
                        //'seconds: ' + t.seconds;
```

You might have forgot to comment last "+" in second line.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/72v5sofn/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = 'days: ' + t.days + '<br>' +
                          'hours: ' + t.hours + '<br>';
```